# Need help with the meanings of these expressions that describing a person's voice よく通るきれいな声 and リバーブのかかった透明感のある声

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

When reading, I met this sentence that describes a girl's voice as よく通るきれいな声 and リバーブのかかった透明感のある声. It's hard for me to understand (I can only guess that her voice is normally already clear and lovely, but since she's in a bathroom, her voice sounds like an echo ??).

Hope someone can explain its correct meaning to me o/

> **ただでさえよく通るきれいな声が風呂場なので、リバーブのかかった透明感のある声に聞こえる。**

Answer (score 2):

- **よく通る声**: Well-projected voice; the voice that is easily heard and understood by an audience even in a large space.
- **きれいな声**: Beautiful voice.
- **リバーブのかかった声**: Echoed or reverberated voice. (Everyone's voice will be echoed in a bathroom, so this is natural.)
- **透明感のある声** (or 透き通った声): This is a way of describing a clear, smooth or pure voice. It's the opposite of a husky voice. A voice may sound clearer if the low frequency components are cut or masked by the environment.

Comment: thanks 4 your explanation, though this is a simple sentence, the way the writer had used to compares a person's voice with a quality/trait from a singer's voice made me confused. I can only understand it simply as : "Because she's in the bathroom, her already beautiful-loud and clear voice. now sounds like an echoing clear voice of a pure maiden/ opera singer." ( i guess the writer wanted to says that she's a pure maiden judging from her voice ? But i'm not sure about the nuances in this sentence, since i'm not native JP to begin with.)

Comment: @casualreader I don't know what her voice is usually like, but generally speaking, 美しい声 is not necessarily 透明感のある声. A husky voice can be beautiful too.